# Backend on swarm

Tags: swarm

I am currently building a dapp on my server which I would like to port to swarm or ipfs and make it completely decentralized.

The initial app will be these components - front end javascript app - backend php app - smart contract

I know there wont be a problem with putting front end on swarm and contract to ethereum network, but how about php backend? Can I make that part decentralized, or will I have to put it on my server? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't run your php backend on swarm. What's generally done is all business logic that needs to be trusted is done in smart contracts, and the frontend does any processing it may need to do for the end user. You could look into [TrueBit](https://medium.com/@simondlr/an-intro-to-truebit-a-scalable-decentralized-computational-court-1475531400c3) as well, which is essentially a decentralized computation marketplace protected by fraud proofs.